# How to handle QComboBox signals in inner classes

Tags: qt, inner-classes

I am using Qt5 and I have created a class "outer" with an "inner" class. The "inner" class has two QComboBox "cb1" and "cb2" objects as private variables.

In the principle, the displayed text of the second QComboBox, "cb2", depends of the current text of the first QComboBox "cb1". In fact, it is easy to implement a connection between these two, using signals and slots by writing the appropriate slot.

The problem is that Qt does not support writing slots inside an inner class. That makes me confused.

How can I handle a connection between these two QComboBoxes in the "inner" class?

For some code,

```
class Outer : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT
  // private variables;

  class Inner : public QWidget
  {
    QComboBox *cb1, *cb2;
    // Other variables;
    public:
    // Public methods
    public slots:
    void setIndex(int i);
  };
  // Other things;
};
```

Inner Implementation

```
Outer::Inner::Inner()
{
  // Useless things;
  connect(cb1, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setIndex(int)));
}

Outer::Inner::setIndex(int i)
{
  // Some stuff to retrieve the correct index in cb2;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to use an inner-class in that case? Is it really necessary? You could document it as private and un-nest it!

Comment: In fact, it is a QTabWidget with QWidget tabs as inner classes. I do not want to implement tab widgets as separate classes because I do not want those tabs to be used anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt 5, any method can be connected to a signal, whether marked as a slot or not, so what you are describing is a non problem.

You need to use the modern `connect` syntax, and it will work fine:

```
connect(cb1, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, this, &Outer::Inner::setIndex);
```

Of course, nothing else will work correctly: the `qobject_cast` mechanism won't work, metadata will be wrong, etc.

An inner class cannot be a `QObject`. I completely fail to see the point of it. Make it a local class in the `.cpp` file instead of an inner class.

Comment: I just tried the connect syntax and got the following error: C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'overloaded-function' to 'const char *'
Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function

Comment: The inner classes works fine as QObjects. Can you please explain why you do not recommend that kind of usage,

Comment: @Patrik They do not work fine, because you cannot add the `Q_OBJECT` macro to them. And without that macro you don't have a valid `QObject` instance. You don't need the inner class at all. Seriously. Just remove it, and make it a stand-alone class within the `.cpp` file. Of course you'll have to `#include "foo.moc"` at the end of the `foo.cpp` file (for example).

Comment: @Patrik Are you trying this in Qt 4? I'm explicit in the answer that this is for Qt 5.

Comment: @Kubar, sorry I ran into an Internet issue yesterday. It is Qt5 as written in the beginning of my post. The version of the connect() function was helpful, but obviously, it does not work for an overloaded signal function. So I created a subclass of QComboBox in which I added a new signal and used it as the type for cb1 and it works.

Comment: @Kubar I am aware of the fact that inner classes are limited in Qt. But for what I need it is just fine.

Comment: @Patrik "it does not work for an overloaded signal " Sure it does work. You just need to write your C++ code correctly: cast the method pointer to a proper type to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: @Kubar, you are right. In fact, that was simple connect(cb1, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), this, &UDial::MUDial::setIndex);

Answer (score 0):

From your code I don't get a reason why you need an inner class at all.

If you just want to avoid the possibility to use the Class somewhere else, I would recommend to put it in a anonymous namespace.

```
namespace {
class YourAnonymousClass{
...
}
}

class TheOtherClass {
...
}
```